# Can't install "App name" error in all devices.Not to specific users

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-gradle-plugin

Can't install play store build in any device. Installation fails with cant install "App name " pop up. Release build is working fine in all devices(I tried sharing the build to friends), testlab run was also success full, no error pre-launch report.

The app was rejected initially as I added all age group but did not provide the test account details(All access in the app is restricted). As I provided it, play store approved it and the app was published. I have tried to upload the apk file instead of .aap.Still, the issue persists. I ran it in the test lab and could find no issues. There are no issues in the pre-launch report.

```
android:testOnly="false" //in manifest 
android.injected.testOnly=false // gradle.properties
```

I uploaded the signed .aap build to play store. After getting published I could download but as the installation process starts it stops with a pop up Can't install "App name". The log that I got during this process is

> Error -504 while installing com.xxxx.xxxx.xxx.xxxx: INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY: installPackageLI

But it is not a test build, it is a signed release build.I have already added `android:testOnly="false"` in manifest and `android.injected.testOnly=false` in `gradle.properties`. As mentioned in other discussions, it is not device specific as I couldn't install in any device.